# Bi-directional @OneToOne mapping creating records using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

When saving a bi-directional @OneToOne mapping, is hibernate supposed to make a record on both tables?

I have a table `interview` with column `applicant_id` that references `applicant` table with field `interview_id` and vice versa, the columns being the FKs.

When creating a column by executing `session.save(theInterview)` is hibernate supposed to create a record in `applicant` table `applicant_id`? Do I need to update the existing record myself or am I doing things wrong?

> Edit

Just was working on my JSP file and noticed that I could see that the reference exists on the applicant too. But the query on the DB shows the field empty?

> Hibernate Mapping

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="applicant_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "interview_id")
private Interview interview_id;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id", nullable=false)
private Applicant applicant_id;
```

> `Interview_id` column on an `applicant` after recording an interview instance.

[image: db]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide your Hibernate mapping? What your asking about is Cascade, i.e. should Hibernate cascade save of the Applicant. That depends entirely on whether Hibernate has been instructed to cascade save on the relationship.

Comment: Please see my edits, I noticed that the reference is there from applicants side but no record in the DB.

Comment: Try getting rid of the JoinColumn annotation on Interview in the Applicant class. The mappedBy field in the OneToOne annotation defines the mapping of the child to the parent.

Comment: Still no record of this in the DB. See added image.